# HTTP status 503 erorr for SOLR 5.0.0

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

I installed solr 5.0.0 in my windows 8 system and apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC5.exe ,my tomcat is listening to 8080 port.

I have copied all the 5 jars and log4j.properties from C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\solr\solr-5.0.0\solr-5.0.0\solr-5.0.0\server\lib\ext to tomcats lib folder .

`jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar`
`jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar` 
`log4j-1.2.17.jar`
`slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar`
`slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar`

Added `-Dsolr.solr.home=C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\solr\solr-5.0.0\solr-5.0.0\solr-5.0.0\` to tomcat service java options.

My tomcat server is up but  solr `http://localhost:8080/solr/` throws below an error

`HTTP Status 503 - Server is shutting down or failed to initialize`

`type Status report`

`message Server is shutting down or failed to initialize`

`description The requested service is not currently available.`

`Apache Tomcat/8.0.0-RC5`.

I tried various options like changing the tomcat port from 8080 to 8983. modifying solr.xml file . None of the solutions worked, may be because I am using solr 5.0.0 . could any one help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According Solr Doc: "Beginning with Solr 5.0, Solr is no longer distributed as a "war" (Web Application Archive) suitable for deployment in any Servlet Container.  Solr is now distributed as a stand alone java server application, including start and stop scripts for use on Unix and MS-Windows platforms, as well as an installation script for setting up a "production" installation of Solr on *nix platforms managed via /etc/init.d.... ... Internally, Solr is still implemented via Servlet APIs and is powered by Jetty -- but this is simply an implementation detail.  `Deployment as a "webapp" to other Servlet Containers (or other instances of Jetty) is not supported, and may not work in future 5.x versions of Solr when additional changes are likely to be made to Solr internally to leverage custom networking stack features`."  I don't know if it means you can't deploy slr 5.0 to other container, like Tomcat. See full description [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+4+to+Solr+5)